# JavaScript json split object and update

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

How do i split json object and update them according to the ID. I heard to use stringify! and how do i implement the function to update the object?

```
<input type="text" value="{"id":"1","price":"30.00","edit":0},
{"id":"2","price":"8.00","edit":0}" id="json" />

**code:**
var json = $('#json').val().split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  alert(json);
}
//(seems its splitting every comma it finds).
```

Im trying to archive:

- Split the object {"id":"1","price":"30.00","edit":0}, {"id":"2","price":"8.00","edit":0}
- Update depends on selected ID.
- and then save and it return same object format but with updated value.

hope my question clears enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of string split and parsing.. Try using `$.parseJSON` like below,

```
$.parseJSON("[" + $('#json').val() + "]");
```

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/QUTu9/

Also fixed the quotes in html like below,

```
<input type="text" value='{"id":"1","price":"30.00","edit":0},
{"id":"2","price":"8.00","edit":0}' id="json" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work since you have quote problem. Easiest solution is to surround it in single quotes.

```
<input type="text" value='{"id":"1","price":"30.00","edit":0},{"id":"2","price":"8.00","edit":0}' id="json" />
```

Do not split it, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your the syntax looks a bit messed up , Surround your value using single Quotes

```
value='{"id":"1","price":"30.00","edit":0}, {"id":"2","price":"8.00","edit":0}'
```